# Customize the auto generation of Post Slug in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When we add new post in wordpress, after supplying the post title, the slug is generated automatically. I need to edit that auto generation module so that i can add some arbitrary number in the end of the slug automatically. How to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use the hard-coded version that the OP used here. When he did that, there was not a filter available. More recently, since 3.3, a filter was added.

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'custom_unique_post_slug', 10, 4 );
function custom_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type ) {
    if ( $custom_post_type == $post_type ) {
        $slug = md5( time() );
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

However this method will change the slug every time you save the post... Which was what I was hoping for...

**EDIT:**

This kind of works for limiting the generation to just once. The only drawback is that it creates one version when ajax runs after creating the title, then it creates another, permanent slug when the post is saved.

```
function custom_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type ) {
    if ( $custom_post_type == $post_type ) {
        $post = get_post($post_ID);
        if ( empty($post->post_name) || $slug != $post->post_name ) {
            $slug = md5( time() );
        }
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a plugin to hook into the `wp_insert_post_data` filter so you can update the slug before the post is sent for insertion into the database:

```
function append_slug($data) {
    global $post_ID;

    if (empty($data['post_name'])) {
        $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title'], $post_ID);
        $data['post_name'] .= '-' . generate_arbitrary_number_here();
    }

    return $data;
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'append_slug', 10);
```

Note that this function requires that you allow WordPress to auto-generate the slug first, meaning you must not enter your own slug before generating, and it cannot update existing posts with the number.

Comment: Ok. can you please explain the flow of control here? I'm adding a filter, means when ever the function `wp_insert_post_data` is called, it must pass through the function i defined i.e. `append_slug`, right? what does that 3rd parameter of add_filter (i.e. `10`) do?

Comment: @Bibhas: After WordPress is done generating the post slug, it immediately calls all functions that apply to the `wp_insert_post_data` filter (it's not actually a PHP function itself). WordPress passes `$data` and `$postarr` based on the post being updated so you can access `$data['post_name']` (the slug). After you modify the slug and `return $data`, WordPress will have the updated post data, ready to be inserted or updated in the DB. Just make this a plugin, activate it and WordPress will handle the rest automatically. I believe this filter is called every time you save a post.

Comment: BTW, That `10` .. What does it do?

Comment: 10 is just an arbitrary value for telling WordPress when to call this filter function if there's anything else hooking onto that function. It shouldn't matter that much in your case.

Comment: This error is occurring - `Missing argument 2 for append_slug()`

Comment: Try changing `function append_slug($data, $postarr) {` to `function append_slug($data) {`

Comment: I'm doing this - 
`function append_slug($data) {
    $data['post_name'] .= "-" . get_random_number();
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'append_slug', 10);

function get_random_number(){
    $random=rand(11111,99999);
    return $random;
}`

But the slug being generated is like this `44049-99894` .. whereas it should be like `test-post-99894` ..

Comment: @Bibhas: Then something is wrong with my code. Could you give me a while to figure it out and I'll update my answer?

Comment: @Bibhas: I've updated my function, can you check if this works?

Comment: @BoltClock From what i can figure, the $data['post_name'] is coming with default blank value.. not the already generated slug.

Comment: @Bibhas: I found that WordPress generates the slug only **after** `wp_insert_post_data`, which is the problem here. I can't find any filters that it calls after generating the slug.

Comment: :( Ok.. Lets see. Btw, for further references, here is the $data array when its being filtered. http://iambibhas.pastebin.com/LQNmuYrR

Comment: @Bibhas: Exactly. If you look at wp-includes/post.php, under `function wp_insert_post`, you should observe that the slug is only generated after the filter call. So what I'm doing is copying how WordPress auto-generates it, if it's not already there, then appending the random number.

Answer (score 2):

Test this : (paste it into functions.php)

```
function append_slug($data) {
global $post_ID;

if (!empty($data['post_name']) && $data['post_status'] == "publish" && $data['post_type'] == "post") {

        if( !is_numeric(substr($data['post_name'], -4)) ) {
            $random = rand(1111,9999);
            $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title($data['post_title'], $post_ID);
            $data['post_name'] .= '-' . $random;
        }

}
 return $data; } add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'append_slug', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   add_filter('post_link','postLinkFilter', 10, 3);

   /**
    * Manipulates the permalink
    *
    * @param string $permalink
    * @param stdClass $post
    * @return string
    */
   function postLinkFilter($permalink,stdClass $post){
        return $permalink.'?12345';
   }
```

Untested in that scenario, but I have already used it, should work with a minimum of changes, but try and test it REALLY Carefully .

In any Case, don't use `rand()` here or something alike, since the function must return the same link for the same post every time, otherwise you will have some serious problems.

Have fun!

Comment: Actually, I want it to generate random number and store the slug like that.

Comment: ah, so you want to manipulate the post-name of the post, not directly the slug creation process, in that case go with @BoltClock, but make sure to check if thats an insert or an update, otherwise your would append another random number each time you update an article - and I'm sure you don't wanna do that ;)

Comment: @Bidhas don't mention it, would probably be possible to check if `$postarr` already has an `ID` - but I'm not a 100% on that thou

Comment: Checking that. Will post if it does.

Comment: post_link doesn't update the actual slug, it just updates the link returned for get_permalink() type functions. It is somewhat superficial. Also, there is page_link and post_type_link for different applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should operate with `wp_ajax_sample-permalink` **action**  and `name_save_pre` **filter**.

More examples here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190314/42702