# WordPress how to hook onto slug generator

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, slug

I'd like to change the slug that is automatically generated when creating a post.

[image]

I'd like to add a meta before, making a thing like `[meta]-test-slug-2`

I guess there's a hook on when WordPress automatically creates a slug, and if I could find it, I could inject that meta before the title when creating the slug.

So is there a hook that exists? If so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$prefix` variable to fit your needs:

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'prefix_wp_unique_post_slug', 2, 6 );
function prefix_wp_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {
    if ( $post_type == 'post' ) {

        $prefix = 'meta-';
        if ( strripos($slug, $prefix) !== 0 ) {
            $slug = $prefix . $slug;
        }
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to give a good priority to the hook! If you dont, some plugins might put it back to the original

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518527/customize-the-auto-generation-of-post-slug-in-wordpress).

In short the filter `wp_unique_post_slug` will allow you to modify the slug.

But it seems that is called with every save of the post, so I would recommend some logic to only prefix on the first save, so users can edit the slug as they like.

Comment: Tried that question, didn't seem to work. Wondered if it was not what I tought it was.

Comment: So does your code not run at all on wp_unique_post_slug? or is it a priority issue (i.e. someone else comes along later to change the slug in a different way).