# Randomizing post urls

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My custom posts need to be protected by a simple version of hashing.
I have been searching on google and stack overflow for about 4 hours now but i can't seem to find the right answer.

Is there a way to change the slug created for new posts on ID level and hash it?
So instead of having:
wordpress.com/blog/143

Hashing the id and have that as url:
wordpress.com/blog/202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$custom-posts_structure = '/custom-post/'. md5('%custom-post%');
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%custom-post%", '([a-z0-9]+)', "custom-post=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('custom-post', $custom-posts_structure, false);
```

I desperately tried the above code but that will just hash the string and doesn't retrieve the unique IDs.

Comment: every time then using "md5('%custom-post%')" you will get same hash, if you wanna get different use unique data (it can be append or prepend) ex: md5('%custom-post%'.time()) - it hash the string with current timestamp

Comment: Applying that will make no difference because wordpress treats it like a universal catergory and not like a unique link. It will just make all my posts have the same url with the same time hashed into it.

Comment: _“Is there a way to change the slug created for new posts”_ - for that part, you should hook into the appropriate place - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518527/customize-the-auto-generation-of-post-slug-in-wordpress Whether this will even need much else after that, not sure right now. This would basically just replace the `post_name` with something different, so if you use the default routing that is _based_ on the post names, I think you might not need to add anything to the rewriting setup itself.

Comment: why do you think this process gives you "protection"? Protection from what, exactly? Maybe I missed something but its unclear what you think the benefit of this work will be.

Comment: @ADyson I don't. The posts are newly created user data that need to be open in public. Since it doesnt require the users to be logged in to add data to their record they have a 15 minute time window. But just having a ID as link would make it too easy for non techies to go into other peoples record. Instead of using md5 the data will have their own encryption in production.

Comment: "Since it doesnt require the users to be logged in to add data to their record (...)" Out of curiosity, how do you know then which records belong to who?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the link. Looked into it and tried it. I seem to get an error on creating the post: ```Undefined variable: custom_post_type```. Dont know how to use the filter or where to call for the function. Never worked with the filters much and the post doesnt explain much either unfortunately. Looking into filters now.

Comment: @cabrerahector users get redirected to the record from a external program that knows the record. The external program gets the url on visit.

Comment: "just having a ID as link would make it too easy for non techies to go into other peoples record"....as the well-known phrase says: "security by obscurity is not security". If you don't want people to be able to get to other people's stuff, use some proper authentication & authorisation. Even if you make the link more complicated, it doesn't make it undiscoverable. It may be searchable or findable by other means (both within your application and using other tools) and users are also very prone to sharing links with each other (either on purpose or accidentally).

Comment: @ADyson very well said. Thats why no one but admins can see the data. The record they get send to is only used for filling in a blank form that is "open" to the "public" for just 15 minutes. Its just to prevent trollers from filling in other peoples forms. No data exposed. And i am pretty convinced that the encryption wont be cracked in 15 minutes to just fill in other peoples form.

Comment: It's not about cracking the encryption - that's irrelevant as far as I can see, it's just the fact that in theory, someone other than the person you intended could visit that link (even within the relatively short time window), and fill in the data, and you would never know. Depends how "interesting" the data is, or whether incorrect information would cause a big problem in any way. I can't answer that as I don't know the nature of this data or your business, so maybe this solution is "good enough" for your purpose, but just be aware that it certainly isn't foolproof.

Comment: @CBroe my previous comment to you was out of pure exhaustion. The filter solved my exact issue thanks!

Comment: Great! I transformed my comment into a short answer.

Comment: @ADyson i really do appreciate your awareness! And I think a lot of people fall short on the problems you are addressing. But my case isnt doomed if someone is able to get into link. Its just a bit of extra information they can add, but it won't be a big problem if not filled in or if someone els did (The extra data is not sensitive). I just want to prevent easy trolling but it isnt necessary to be fully secured since easy and fast is the biggest selling point of the feature and it not being sensitive data of course .

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the slug created for new posts

For that part, you should hook into the appropriate place - see [Customize the auto generation of Post Slug in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518527/customize-the-auto-generation-of-post-slug-in-wordpress)

This would basically just replace the `post_name` with something different (your hash), so if you use the default routing that is based on the post names, you should not need to add anything to the rewriting setup itself.